# Finding derivative at specific time on space curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to do some practice questions in my book, but I don't know how to do this specific question:

Suppose the function $F(x,y,z,t)$ satisfies $F_x(3,9,18,3)=1$, $F_y(3,9,18,3)=-2$, $F_z(3,9,18,3)=3$, and $F_t(3,9,18,3)=4$. Find $dF/dt$ at time $t=3$ on the space curve $$r(t) = t\vec{i} + t^2 \vec{j} + (2/3)t^3\vec{k}$$

The answer is supposed to be $47$, but I don't know how to get it. Could someone please give a detailed explanation on how $47$ was acquired?

Comment: What is the difference between F_t and dF/dt? Aren't they essentially the same with just using different notations?

Answer (score 0):

This question wants you to consider the composition of $F$ and $r$,
and take its derivative w.r.t. $t$. That is,
$$
F\circ r=F\left(t,t^{2},\frac{2}{3}t^{3},t\right)
$$
and find
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left[F\circ r\right].
$$
Once you have found this derivative, you need to evaluate it at $t=3$.

Step-by-step: using the chain rule,
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left[F\circ r\right]=F_{x}\left(t,t^{2},\frac{2}{3}t^{3},t\right)+F_{y}\left(t,t^{2},\frac{2}{3}t^{3},t\right)2t+F_{z}\left(t,t^{2},\frac{2}{3}t^{3},t\right)2t^{2}+F_{t}\left(t,t^{2},\frac{2}{3}t^{3},t\right)
$$
so that at $t=3$,
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left[F\circ r\right]\mid_{t=3}=\underbrace{F_{x}\left(3,9,18,3\right)}_{1}+\underbrace{F_{y}\left(3,9,18,3\right)}_{-2}6+\underbrace{F_{z}\left(3,9,18,3\right)}_{3}18+\underbrace{F_{t}\left(3,9,18,3\right)}_{4}=47
$$

Comment: How do I know when to dot product the two equations or how do I know when r become the variables of F?

Comment: From the context of the question. In this case, $r$ is the trajectory of a particle (or something) and $F$ is some function that gives a value to each point in this trajectory.